# How to open emacs magit on a specific bare repo from the command line?

Tags: magit, shell

I'm trying to switch over from neovim.  I use this alias to open vimagit on my config bare repo: `alias configit=GIT_DIR=$HOME/.cfg GIT_WORK_TREE=$HOME nvim -c MagitOnly`.  I use this command when I want to see any changes to my dotfiles in my home repository (created following this [guide](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles)).    Trying to replicate this with a similar alias or script to work with emacs magit.